# Is this parametrization of the interior of a triangle wrong? What's wrong with it?

Tags: geometry

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be points in $\mathbb R^n$  that are not collinear. Let

$$I=\{X:X=A+\lambda\overrightarrow{AB}+\mu\overrightarrow{AC} \text{ where } \lambda,\mu,\lambda+\mu\in[0,1]\}.$$

Then $I$ is the interior of the triangle, including the line segments.

According to [John Alexiou](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4784742/1210203), my above parametrization is wrong. Is it wrong? Why?

Comment: This seems correct to me. I believe linear transformations reduce the problem to the special case in $\Bbb R^2$ when $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(0,1)$, where the parametrization is clearly valid.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. When $\lambda+\mu=1$ you go along the edge $BC$, for smaller values of $\lambda+\mu$ you are proportionately more into the interior.

Comment: The answer to the other question has been modified so it no longer says your parameterization is "incorrect", only "quirky". I think it's useful to know about the other parameterization, but I think you can use yours at least for the problem you were originally trying to solve.